# How do I get more insight in what's going wrong with my script?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include "../../../wp-load.php";

$groups = array();

if (($handle = fopen("groupData.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $group = array('group_id'    => 'SOME ID',
                'creator_id'  => '1',
                'name'        => $data[0], 
                'description' => $data[1], 
                'slug' => groups_check_slug(sanitize_title(esc_attr($data[2]))), 
                'date_created' => gmdate( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ), 
                'status' => 'public', 
                'enable_forum' => '1'
 );
        $groups[] = $group;
    }   
    fclose($handle);
}

foreach ($groups as $group) {
    groups_create_group($group);
} 

?>
```

When I open the script in my browser everything seems fine, I get a blank screen and the error_log is empty. But it doesn't do what it is written for. Do you have any tips how I get get more insight of what is going wrong?

The purpose of the script is to create groups in BuddyPress from a .csv-file.

Comment: "But it doesn't do what it is written for." <- What is it supposed to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: It is supposed to create groups in BuddyPress from a .csv-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called debugging:

```
$handle = fopen("groupData.csv", "r");
if (!$handle) {
    trigger_error('Error establishing handle');
} else {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        var_dump($data);

        $group = array(
                'group_id'    => 'SOME ID',
                'creator_id'  => '1',
                'name'        => $data[0], 
                'description' => $data[1], 
                'slug' => groups_check_slug(sanitize_title(esc_attr($data[2]))), 
                'date_created' => gmdate( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ), 
                'status' => 'public', 
                'enable_forum' => '1'
        );

        var_dump($group);

        $groups[] = $group;
    }

    fclose($handle);

    var_dump($groups);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a difference between your code and @karim79 ?

Comment: @Anders You mean between `var_dump` and `print_r`? Not really, only the output information differs slightly.

Comment: You've also var_dumped $data, which could be helpful if the csv isn't in a format that PHP likes, where as the other guy just did print_r($groups).  Might consider echoing some `<br />` in there though, to break up the sections of dumped data.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try outputting some of the data you are working with, to ensure that the script is actually getting executed, like:

```
print_r($groups);
```

If you are still getting a blank screen, it could be the [White Page of Death](http://blog.isnoop.net/2008/10/24/php-closing-tags-stealing-your-cookies/) - that is, your script is failing silently without any message. Try these:

1 - Remove whitespace before any opening tags.

2 - Remove your closing tags altogether (except for embedded PHP tags, mixed with output).